# Slow response in chat messages using cronjob

Tags: mysql, cron, response

I have several accounts in Mercado Libre, the idea of the project is to be able to respond to messages (post-sales chat) and questions (pre-sales) from customers through my own platform.

The question section works great (It has a small delay maybe by the same cronjob). However, the messages section does not work well at all, you send a message and it takes a long time to send, you select something and it takes too long to select, it is a functioning problem, the chat should deliver instantly.
The code used is php, ajax, curl and js. Database used is mysql

Why can I do?